# SQL query Total sale

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sale table and would like to calculate a total.

[Here is the SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3c03/1).

**The expected result is 482.33.**

Some one (@rs) helped me with the query before, but it does not work in this case. I would like to get the total of this customer between '2012/12/07' to '2012/12/09' subtract *any RETURNED (negative) item* with the same SKU as an item purchased during the date range.

The result came out wrong. Could you please help.

Comment: Where did you get the 482 total?  Did you manually add up the numbers to see the expected results?

Comment: it's actually 482.33. Yes I added up the numbers. There is one return item (-111.96) on 12/23/2012.

Comment: -111.96 is on 12/23 that is AFTER 12/9.  Either change your parameters, or expect different results

Comment: Isn't your date range max 12/09  isn't 12/23 after that?

Comment: If you want to consider dates between '2012/12/07' to '2012/12/09' then why do you add up -111.96 which happened on 12/23/2012?

Comment: If you expand the date range to 12/23, the total is 560.24 (you can't include one record from 12/23 and not the others).  As for why your formula is including the 12/23 dates when it clearly says 12/09 and the upper limit, I have no idea.  You have made a simple query FAR TOO COMPLEX.  Without understanding why, I don't want to take the time to debug.

Comment: items between 12/07-12/09 are valid subtract any return items (same SKU). Any negative items are considered RETURNED items. So if customer return after they purchased during 12/07-12/09 will not be counted.

Comment: You need to change your question.  You are not trying to find the total in a date range, you are trying to find the total in a date range, less any returns after the date range where the sku matches.

Comment: updated my question... sorry for the confused!

Comment: ... Are you actually using `float` for a currency type?  You realize you can't exactly represent certain values, right (like `.1`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another option:

```
DECLARE @customer varchar(10) = '1111111111' 
DECLARE @from date = '12/07/12'
DECLARE @till date = DATEADD(DAY, 2, @from)
DECLARE @exclusiveTill date = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @till) 
-- added @exclusiveTill based on the comments

SELECT
  [sub].[custid],
  MAX([sub].[LatestDop]) AS [dateid],
  SUM([sub].[PriceSum]) AS [price]
FROM
(
  SELECT
    [custid],
    MAX([dop]) AS [LatestDop],
    [sku],
    SUM([price]) AS [PriceSum],
    SUM(CASE WHEN [price] >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [numberOfPositives]
  FROM [sale]
  WHERE
    [custid] = @customer
    AND [dop] >= @from
    AND (CASE WHEN [price] < 0 THEN @till ELSE [dop] END) < @exclusiveTill
  GROUP BY
    [custid],
    [sku]
) AS [sub]
WHERE 
  [sub].[numberOfPositives] > 0
GROUP BY 
  [sub].[custid]
```

This was made with [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3c03/68).

This query is rather literally translating your answer and comments into sql:

- All sales in a certain timespan
- Where negative sales after this timespan should be included
- But a negative sale should have at least one positive with the same sku (in the timespan)
- And the sum of all prices of the sales satisfying the above criteria should be determined

Comment: The use of `CASE` makes this feel slightly hacky.  Also, please read [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) about `BETWEEN` for date/time types - while you don't use the clause itself, you are using an inclusive upper-bound, which will produce the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and pointing out the BETWEEN-problem. I'll improve my answer. Further more, you are pointing at the CASE used in the WHERE-clause I suppose? Isn't this a commonly used approach in SQL Server? Is it a personal dislike or are there any risks involved?

Comment: I can't necessarily speak to common practice on the platform; the part that feels the most hacky is the effect of comparing `@till` to itself (originally, or to a new variable now).  Hmm, I think I tend to prefer `CASE` only for `SELECT` clauses - everything else I tend to use 'regular' logic (`AND`, `OR`, etc) - something like `price < 0 OR dop < @till` is my preference.  Oh, 'till' has a specific meaning for retail business (the machine that a cashier operates); something like `@includePurchasesBefore` is obvious and unambiguous.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thanks for explaining, I'll take this into account in my future work. I'll leave this answer "as is", since it is accepted in this state.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
;WITH T AS
(
  SELECT * FROM sale WHERE Price > 0
  AND [dop] BETWEEN '12/07/12' AND '12/09/12'
  UNION
  SELECT A.* FROM sale a WHERE price < 0
  AND EXISTS (SELECT SKU FROM sale x
            WHERE x.Price > 0 AND a.sku = x.sku
            AND a.custid = x.custid 
            AND x.[dop] BETWEEN '12/07/12' AND '12/09/12')
)
SELECT Custid, max(dop) dateid, sum(price) Price
FROM T
GROUP BY custid;
```

[SQL DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f3c03/42)

Comment: You should include `Price = 0` as a 'purchased' item, because this might change the date-of-purchase.  Also, [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) has reasons why `BETWEEN` shouldn't be used for date/time types, especially on MS SQL Server

Comment: thanks again @rs, it works at SQL Fiddle but it's not working correctly in my database, the result came out 464.38 in the actual database...debugging... what could it go wrong!!!

Answer (score 0):

with the new information try this:

```
DECLARE @datemin date = '12/7/12',
        @datemax date = '12/9/12',
        @custid varchar(10)='1111111111'
;WITH RECS AS(
    SELECT custid,dop,sku,Price 
      FROM sale 
      WHERE dop BETWEEN @datemin AND @datemax AND custid=@custid AND price>=0)

SELECT custid,MAX(dop)dateid,SUM(price)price
FROM(
  SELECT custid,dop,price FROM RECS
  UNION ALL
  SELECT custid,dop,price FROM sale 
      WHERE sku IN (SELECT sku FROM RECS) AND price < 0 AND dop > @datemax)t
GROUP BY custid
```

It isn't pretty, but it shows a totally different approach, and it was fast to put together.

You create a list of transactions within the date range, plus a list of negative transactions after the date range where the sku happened within the daterange and get your totals from there.

CAUTION:  This has TROUBLE written all over it.

What happens if the same sku was purchased prior to the date range AND within the date range, then the prior purchase was returned?  This would reduce it from the date range.

How would you know which was actually returned?

Why not decrement the return from the period in which it actually happened?  This is very common, especially if the return happens some time later.

There are many more questions to be answered, but that just gives you something to think about.

Comment: Please see [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) about `BETWEEN` and date/time types.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse those are things people should be aware of when writing code, thanks for reminding us.  However, I disagree that it is evil.  There is NOTHING wrong with using it, so long as you understand what it does and what it does is what you want.